# Why is $\vert I=1,I_3=1\rangle = -p\bar n$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, isospin-symmetry

My book doesn't explain well how to build a doublet of antiparticles that transforms the same way the particle doublet $(p,n)^T$ (proton neutron) does.

They claim  $$\tag 1 \vert I=1,I_3=1\rangle = -p\bar n$$ for a composite nucleon-antinucleon system.

**Why is $(1)$ true?**

Perhaps it's just bad notation in the book? I got confused because the [Clebsch-Gordan for $(1)$ comes with a $+1$ and not a $-1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#j1.3D1.2F2.2C_j2.3D1.2F2), but perhaps one should insclude this negative sign into the CG coeff? That is $(1)$ should be

$$\tag 2 \vert I =1,I_3=1\rangle =\underbrace{\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle}_{p}~\Big(\underbrace{-\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle}_{-\bar n}\Big)?$$

Comment: I am down-voting this question, because I answered v2.  Then, the question was edited to something different.

Comment: @QuantumDot that's not a good reason to downvote a question. It would be better to edit your answer, or delete it if you don't want to have an answer posted anymore. See also [this proposal on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2322).

Answer (score 1):

The $(p,n)$ isospin doublet follows the same rules as the $(u,d)$ quark doublet.  So the nucleon-antinucleon isospin triplet  should have the same wavefunctions as the pions:
\begin{align*}
\big|\pi^-\big> &= \big|\bar ud\big> \\
\big|\pi^0\big> &= \frac{\big|\bar uu\big> - \big|\bar dd\big>}{\sqrt2}
\\
\big|\pi^+\big> &= -\big|\bar du\big>
\end{align*}
Your $p\bar n$ is analogous to the $\pi^+$.

The minus sign of the $I_3=1$ state can be safely absorbed into its normalization, but it comes from the same place as the relative minus sign in the $\pi^0$ state ([not that I totally understand the reason for that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110719/phase-factors-under-rotations-of-strong-and-weak-isospin)).