# Where does this charge conjugation coefficient come from? Wong's Introductory Nuclear Theory

Tags: nuclear-physics, charge-conjugation

I'm following Wong's *Introductory Nuclear Physics*, 2e. In section 2-4 there's a discussion of charge conjugation I don't fully follow. Something simple is escaping me. The excerpt is produced below, but here's a quick run down:

- The proton state is given as a second-quantization real-particle creation operator acting on the vacuum: $|p\rangle = a^\dagger_{1/2,+1/2} |0\rangle$, where the subscripts refer to the isospin $t=1/2$ of a nucleon and the eigenvalue $t_0=+1/2$ of the third-component of isospin (to distinguish the proton from the neutron $a^\dagger_{1/2,-1/2}|0\rangle$).
- Antiprotons are given as an anti-particle creation operator $|\bar p\rangle=b^\dagger_{1/2,-1/2}$
- It is stated without proof (which is okay) that the two creation operators must be related by $b^\dagger_{t, t_0}=(-1)^{t-t_0}a_{t,-t_0}$
- Then the part I don't understand is how charge conjugation (particle-antiparticle) is given for the proton as $$|p\rangle\xrightarrow[\ C\ ]{}(-1)^{1/2+1/2}|\bar p\rangle$$

**It's unclear to me** how the creation operators and the operator relations are being used together to produce that charge conjugation mapping. If this [other Exchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110719/29216) addresses it, I don't see how or it is beyond me.

What exactly is the mapping $C$ they are using and how is it related to what was previously given? More specifically, what are the detailed steps between 2-23 through 2-25 and 2-26?

I tried starting with the vacuum, then applying the particle-creation, particle-destruction, and anti-particle creation operators but couldn't get their relation; I wasn't sure of my particle destruction operator. Perhaps they are relying on other physics not given in the discussion.

[image: Wong]

Comment: Maybe reading this will help on the definition of operators http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qmoper.html . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qmoper.html  "Associated with each measurable parameter in a physical system is a quantum mechanical operator." charge and charge conjugation are measurable parameters. also this history of the operation https://www.britannica.com/science/charge-conjugation

Comment: Hi @annav. I'm familiar with the ideas of observables and operators. But it's unclear to me how Eqn 2-26 follows from 2-23 through 2-25.

Comment: You are asking about C in the text? I think it represents the act of the writer/reader in changing the charges of the particles. The same for parity. When one does a parity operation it is a change in the coordinates, a spatial inversion. IMHO

Comment: in addition to the above of course, the P operator es dependent on  the coordinates used to model the interactions among  the charges.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110719/44126

Comment: I think I have answered this question long ago here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110719/phase-factors-under-rotations-of-strong-and-weak-isospin  You just need to replace everywhere u--> p and d-->n and you will be done

Comment: @TwoBs So is the idea that Wong could have said "it can be shown that..."? Meaning that it's not a simple step or two to show, and something along the lines of your previous answer is required? I wrote this question assuming I was missing something at the surface level.

Comment: The paragraph in my old answer from long ago that starts with ‘However’ it’s enough to get the gist and it isn’t that complicated after all.

Comment: I don't see Eqn. 2-25 in that answer. How would Wong explain the steps using what was developed?